# Link back to referring page

Tags: php, referrer

What's the best way to link back to the page that a user has just come from?

For example, we have a form that can be opened from a few different locations, and the form has a cancel link - clicking the link should send the user back to where they came from.

The best method that I can think of is to use flash data in the session. If there isn't a flash var available, then it would obviously have to fall back to a default link. But maintaining this through failed validation, etc could become very messy.

Are there any other better alternatives that should be considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` , but keep in mind getting referer data is tricky because a user with technical knowledge could modify the headers sent.

I think it would work great for your need though , just don't base anything critical on it.

Shai.

Comment: ....and there's no guarantee that, even in the absence of user mischief, that the browser will supply a referer

Comment: Of course not, But like most compatibility issues, sometimes you have to target just modern browsers. Anyways, as i said the data isn't always available so don't use it for anything critical.

Answer (score 2):

if your thinking of using a button to go back then simplest would be use history.back() and bind it to onclick event of that button

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are opening the form. best way is to use a GET or POST. for eg.

```
http://myweb.com/?redirurl="referer_url"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden form field in which you can populate with the page it's currently loaded in. It won't burden the session, and it sort of acts as somewhat of a callback ability.

Answer (score -1):

What about `$_SERVER['http_referrer'];`  isn't it a solution to your question?